# Iterating over a vector in reverse direction

Tags: c++, stl, iteration

I need to iterate over a vector from the end to the beginning. The "correct" way is

```
for(std::vector<SomeT>::reverse_iterator rit = v.rbegin(); rit != v.rend(); ++rit)
{
    //do Something
}
```

When `//do Something` involves knowing the actual index, then some calculations need to be done with `rit` to obtain it, like `index = v.size() - 1 - (rit - v.rbegin)`

If the index is needed anyway, then I strongly believe it is better to iterate using that index

```
for(int i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    //do something with v[i] and i; 
}
```

This gives a warning that `i` is signed and `v.size()` is unsigned.
Changing to

`for(unsigned i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)` is just functionally wrong, because this is essentially an endless loop `:)`

What is an aesthetically good way to do what I want to do which

- is warning-free
- doesn't involve casts
- is not overly verbose

Comment: loop condition `i != std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()` ... or use UINT_MAX if you think its to verbose.

Comment: So far, I think doing a cast is looking like the cleanest solution :-)

Comment: just set an upper bound on i, i.e. v.size().

Comment: @Downvoter: Would you be kind to explain the downvote? This was a precise question and I finally got the answer thanks to @Nim.

Comment: @Steve: Suppose the value of the element must be multiplied with its index or something like that :)

Comment: In that case, I think my answer works well, because there's never a need to use indexing.  The arithmetic in maintaining dual loop counters ought to be less costly.

Comment: `for (size_t i = v.size(); i --> 0; )`

Comment: `for(unsigned i : boost::counting_range(v) | boost::adaptors::reversed)`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As you've noted, the problem with a condition of `i >= 0` when it's unsigned is that the condition is always true. Instead of subtracting 1 when you initialize `i` and then again after each iteration, subtract 1 after checking the loop condition:

```
for (unsigned i = v.size(); i-- > 0; )
```

I like this style for several reasons:

- Although `i` will wrap around to `UINT_MAX` at the end of the loop, it doesn't *rely* on that behavior — it would work the same if the types were signed. Relying on unsigned wraparound feels like a bit of a hack to me.
- It calls `size()` exactly once.
- It doesn't use `>=`. Whenever I see that operator in a `for` loop, I have to re-read it to make sure there isn't an off-by-one error.
- If you change the spacing in the conditional, you can make it use the ["goes to" operator](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/11/19/c-goes-to-operator/).

Comment: shoulnd't it be size_t than unsigned ?

Comment: That could be better if you really anticipate having more items than will fit in an `unsigned`, @Yes123, but the formally correct type would be `std::vector<SomeT>::size_type`, or, nowadays, simply `auto`.

Answer (score 17):

There's nothing to stop your `reverse_iterator` loop also using the index as described in multiple other answers.  That way you can use the iterator or index as needed in the `// do the work` part, for minimal extra cost.

```
size_t index = v.size() - 1;
for(std::vector<SomeT>::reverse_iterator rit = v.rbegin(); 
    rit != v.rend(); ++rit, --index)
{
  // do the work
}
```

Though I'm curious to know what you need the index for.  Accessing `v[index]` is the same as accessing `*rit`.

Comment: This is actually the only correct answer for any underlying type that's not random access.  Assuming `std::vector<SomeT>` is typedef'd away somewhere I'd prefer to use the correct iterator in case I later decided to use a list, multiset, map, etc.

Comment: use auto to reduce verbosity.

Answer (score 7):

to be aesthetically pleasing! ;)

```
for(unsigned i = v.size() - 1; v.size() > i; --i)
```

Comment: @Armen, hmm, but unsigned (by default int) *could be* smaller than the `size_type` of `vector`, as to why you could have more than 4bn entries in your vector, that's a different question... :).. okay, okay... I give in...

Comment: And what if v.size() == UINT_MAX ? I know this never happens in practice, but it is a theoric flaw

Comment: @JB: vector::size_type is not unsigned int is also a theoretic flaw. But I honestly don't care about theoretic flaws as long as there is really no practical chance it's gonna backfire – Armen Tsirunyan 7 secs ago edit

Comment: I don't know if it's me not using the wrapping around efficiently, but I usually do it with `for (i = v.size(); i > 0; --i)` and then use `i-1` as the actual index. Matter of preference I guess.

Answer (score 5):

In C++20 one can use ranges (`#include <ranges>`)

```
//DATA
std::vector<int> vecOfInts = { 2,4,6,8 };

//REVERSE VECTOR 
for (int i : vecOfInts | std::views::reverse)
{
     std::cout << i << "  ";
}
```

or if it is required to save in a different variable.

```
//SAVE IN ANOTHER VARIABLE
auto reverseVecOfInts = std::views::reverse(vecOfInts);

//ITERATION
for (int i : reverseVecOfInts)
{
    std::cout << i << "  ";
}
```

Comment: though this approach looks nice, it has performance implications - `reverse` will do _exactly (last - first) / 2 swaps_ , which in certain cases may be a notable overhead

Comment: @AntonK: I think you are talking about `std::ranges::reverse` in `algorithms`. This post is about `std::ranges::views::reverse`. I believe views are light, just like iterators.

Answer (score 2):

*I would prefer the reverse iterator variant, because it's still easy to interpret and allows to avoid index-related errors.*

Sometimes you can simply use the `BOOST_REVERSE_FOREACH`, which would make your code look the following way:

```
reverse_foreach (int value, vector) {
   do_something_with_the_value;
}
```

---

Actually speaking, you can always use `foreach` statements for these kinds of loops, but then they become a bit unobvious:

```
size_t i = 0;

foreach (int value, vector) {
   do_something;
   ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out a do while :

```
std::vector<Type> v;
// Some code 
if(v.size() > 0)
{
    unsigned int i = v.size() - 1;
    do
    {
        // Your stuff
    }
    while(i-- > 0);
}
```

Comment: Okay, no problem ;). I tested the do while and it works. I don't say it is the best solution, but it is one available.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think better way use iterator as you use in first sample and if you need get iterator index you can use 
std::distance to calculate it, if i understand your question

Answer (score 0):

loop condition `i != std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()` ... or use `UINT_MAX` if you think its to verbose.
or another way: 
`for(unsigned j=0, end=v.size(), i=end-1; j<end; --i, ++j)`
or 
`for(unsigned end=v.size(), i=end-1; (end-i)<end; --i)`

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the size to an int if your vector is not huge

```cpp
for (int i = int(v.size()) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    //do something with v[i] and i; 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think that:

```
for(unsigned i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
```

is fine if you check

```
!v.empty()
```

earlier.

Comment: @HardCoder1986: Think again :)

Comment: the code won't work properly because of underflow error. It's better to get rid of subtracting `1` initially, and instead compare for _greater_ this way `for(unsigned i = v.size(); i > 0; --i) { ... }`, but you'll have then use `v[i-1]` to access current element by an index within the loop.

Answer (score -3):

```
for (it = v.end()-1; it != v.begin()-1; --it)
{
}
```

The ["goes to" operator](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/11/19/c-goes-to-operator/) definitely messes with my head.

Comment: @Floella AFAIK, this doesn't work (subtracting integers is not supported for iterators). To iterate in reverse, I think you have to use `std::vector<T>::reverse_iterator` *a la* https://stackoverflow.com/a/4206142/5835083, or use `std::distance` if you really insist on using subtraction.