# Garbage value of iterator value in C++

Tags: c++, string

I am solving a problem where I need to return the last index of '1' in a given string. If not present then return -1. I wrote the following simple code, but for input string input "0" it fails. I tried to debug bu using GDB and I noticed that once loop statement of `index()` function runs once then a garbage value is assigned to iteration variable `i`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int index(string &str) {
    int result = -1;
    for(auto i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if(str[i] == '1')
            return i;
    }
    return result;
}
int main() {
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    cin.ignore();
    while(T--) {
        string str;
        cin >> str;
        cout << index(str) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### What exactly is the problem?

[image]
Notice the value of `i` in the second iteration.

Comment: `i` is of type `size_t`, which is unsigned. It underflowed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traversing a vector in reverse direction with size\_t values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402237/traversing-a-vector-in-reverse-direction-with-size-t-values)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How could that be? The OP is looping until it's < 0.

Comment: @Chipste No, they're looping until it's < 0. Which it never is. So it's looping until some random unspecified value looks like '1', and then some massive `i` is returned.

Comment: Take a look at the image I added and notice the value of `i` in the second iteration. It must be -1 now but It's some different value.

Comment: Your screenshot is really hard to read.  You should just copy and paste the text of your shell session when posting here.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I changed the screenshot.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You realize I'm not the OP, right?

Comment: @Chipster Oops, I intended to ping OP.

Comment: @ArunSuryan The point was to not use a screenshot at all. [We don't like screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has undefined behaviour here:

```
for(auto i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if(str[i] == '1')
        return i;
}
```

[The `length()` of an `std::string` has an unsigned type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size), and since you used `auto` that means your `i` is unsigned too (to be precise, a `std::size_t`).

Such values *never* go below zero. They wrap around to the maximum value of the type (a very large number!).

So, your loop condition does nothing; it's always true. Instead, out-of-bounds accesses `str[i]` then occur until one of the unspecified values that results happens to look like `'1'`. Then, the massive `i` is returned.

It is possible to loop backwards through a standard container or string, but [you have to be careful about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27402237/4386278). My recommendation to you is to use iterators; in this case, [*reverse iterators*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin).

```
for (auto it = str.rcbegin(); it != str.rcend(); ++it)
{
    if (*it == '1')
        return std::distance(it, str.rcend());
}
```

Comment: I got your point. But for taking `i` as following warning occurs: Narrowing conversion from 'unsigned long' to signed type 'int' is implementation-defined. What is a good way to tackle this?

Comment: @ArunSuryan I added a link to some material for you to read. Take your time and study it.